# Can't execute my own program

Tags: command-line, executable

I am learning programming using the OpenGL and SDL library.
Problem is, once the program is built, I can't run it.

(bash: ./nameOfMyProgram Permission denied)

I never had this problem with previous exercises, the files are mine, how could I run them properly?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This has not alot to do with ubuntu ;)

Comment: Where is your pgm directory? If it is in in FAT/NTFS partion ,move it to home folder

Answer (score 2):

`chmod u+x ./nameOfMyProgram` Set eXecute permissions to the file for the User.